# Can self-funded international students be denied admission based on absence of scholarship/fellowship?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, canada, international

Is having a scholarship/fellowship mandatory for graduate studies (MSc) for an international student?

I told my potential supervisor that I can fund my studies on my own through an education loan, but she didn't reply. Can I be denied admission, and what steps (if any) can I take to avoid this?

Comment: `I told my potential supervisor that I can fund my studies on my own through an education loan, but she didn't reply.` There are many reasons why she might not reply. Do you have any reason to believe that self funding is the reason?

Answer (score 4):

> Can self-funded international students be denied admission based on absence of scholarship/fellowship?

Of course they can (and often are). Admission to graduate school also includes an evaluation whether the candidate is likely to graduate, and having funding outside of a scholarship does not change that evaluation. An added problem is that being admitted to the graduate school is only one side of the coin - you also need an advisor willing to work with you. If your application is considered too weak for regular acceptance with a scholarship, it is somewhat likely that you will also have troubles finding an advisor - and admitted students without advisor are often a bit of an administrative headache that admission committees would like to avoid.

Comment: The OP is looking at a master's degree, not a PhD program. Maybe you'd could modify the answer suitably?

Comment: @user153812 Maybe I'm stupid, but where does it say that? I am also not sure if this will change my answer much, at least not for a master-by-research.

Comment: @xLeitix Pre-edit, the question mentioned a MSc degree and had the tag [tag:masters]. I don't know why either/both mentions were removed.

Comment: Sorry, have got those tags back. I believed 'graduate studies' meant master's by default, seems like that was a wrong assumption.